# Facebook OG Image suddenly misbehaving

Tags: facebook, amazon-s3, facebook-opengraph

We've had news articles sharing to facebook correctly for a long time but as of last weekend we are starting to see the wrong og:image when shared to facebook. Using the debugger tool, the first time it is fetched I get a warning "image too small" which is probably why it defaults to another image. But the image in question is not too small. Could this be some issue with headers of my images in Amazon Bucket maybe? Cannot pin point the problem yet.

[image]

Pressing scrape again 2 times then I get the correct og:image

[image]

As an attempt to fix this I have added og:image:width and og:image:height but so far to no avail.

Debugger url: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maltatoday.com.mt%2Fnews%2Fworld%2F79568%2Fsicily_firefighters_caused_fires_for_cash

Comment: Actually adding the og:image:width and og:image:height may have solved it. Strange how we never had these and it was working before.

Will mark question as solved if this works out maybe it will be helpful for someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding og:image:width and og:image:height as additional meta tags solved the issue for me. User nunsy_grey mentioned that this doesn't solve it for some user so worth looking at this [alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45566639/613846)

Answer (score 2):

**Adding Height & Width is NOT enough for everyone.**
I've done the same for my websites and it didn't fixed it. It always needed a second Scraping, and then it will re-fetch the correct image.
Even after adding all of the meta OG tags didn't improve the situation.
I've noticed A LOT of other people experiencing this same issue, and adding height & width meta doesn't solve it.

In this case you'll need to add an **iframe** in your footer, and set it to be invisible and on page load to go to the facebook debugger, and scrape the url one more time for you automatically.
**This is the solution according to Facebook. You'll need to scrape a second time** (reference [best practises](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) under "Pre-caching images"). This is counter productive to be done manually, so just add the following code in your footer and you're done.

```
<iframe style="width:0; height:0; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; position:absolute;" src="https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=<?php the_permalink(); ?>">‌​</iframe>
```

A few notes to keep in mind:

- This link leading to the debugger tool is valid in the time of writing this (August 2017). I've seen the link being different in the past, so if the link has changed in the future, just change the link in the iframe appropriately.
- The part of the url right after "?q=" is the place where you place your link that you're posting to Facebook. I've used the_permalink() because it automatically checks the page's url and puts it in the link. If you'll like to do this for a single post, then just replace this with your actual link. This is for a WordPress php page. If this is not the correct code for your page, then change it into the language you're using.

I hope this helps everyone looking for an answer of this weird Facebook bug. It could have saved me ~6h of my life.
Cheers

Credit to user [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6394404/dan) for giving a clue on how to solve this.

Comment: Did they really recommend scraping a second time? The iframe, while it works, sounds like a bad idea as it will do it for every request. In the case of a site that has A LOT of traffic, I'd think facebook would flag us as a malicious domain or something eventually.

Comment: Luckily for me most of our articles are scraping ok with the OG height and width.

Hopefully this is something facebook would fix soon

Comment: You can see the recommendations by facebook here [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices) under the section "**Pre-caching images**" I know, it seems weird and not really good for high traffic websites but for now I'm using this. As soon as there is a better solution, I'll be changing my website to it.